# Where layer should I put my ViewModel for ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, clean-architecture, mediatr, mediator, onion-architecture

Good day fellow developers.

Sorry if this might not be a valid/confusing question as I am not that proficient with MVC.

With regards to clean architecture principle, what layer should I put my View Model? in entities layer? use case layer? or in presentation layer?

Some of the articles I found, they mentioned to put the ViewModel in **Presentation layer** but I am not sure how I can convert the data from DB to ViewModel if I put it in the mentioned layer.

Currently, this is my implementation. Converting the DB data to ViewModel using AutoMapper in the handler. Just to mention, I am using the Mediator design pattern using Mediatr.

**FeatureController.cs**

```
public class FeatureController : BaseController
{
  private readonly IMediator _mediator;

  FeatureController(IMediator mediator) {
   _mediator = mediator;
  }

  public IActionResult Method1() {
    var vm = _mediator.Send(new FeatureCommand())
    return View(vm);
  }
}
```

**FeatureCommand.cs**

```
public class FeatureCommand : IRequest<SomeViewModel>
{
}
```

**FeatureCommandHandler.cs**

```
public class FeatureCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<FeatureCommand, SomeViewModel>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ISomeRepo _someRepo;

    public void ViewModel(IMapper mapper, ISomeRepo repo) {
      _mapper = mapper;
      _someRepo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<DeviceWrapperDataView> Handle(FeatureCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Insert code to fetch data from DB
        var resultFromDB = repo.GetFromDB();

        return _mapper.Map<SomeViewModel>(resultFromDB);
    }
}
```

I am planning to create the ViewModels in different class library. Same level with the domain layer (inner part of the onion architecture) as for the reason that my UseCase layer needs to use those ViewModel shown in the return part of my Handler class.

Please correct me if my understanding with the clean architecture is wrong. Thank you in advance

Comment: ViewModel is between Application- and UI-Layer as it is like a Mediator between both layers.

Comment: JFI, there is an opposite solution to consider. Keep all the feature components as close to each other as possible: https://codeopinion.com/organize-by-feature/

Comment: @SirRufo, thanks for confirming. If that would be the case, is it okay if I may request for an example or any reference wherein from Application layer, the data from the DB will be passed into a viewmodel? I've searched lots of reference online, but can't find one for MVVM with Clean Architecture + Mediator

Comment: Hello @SerhiiShushliapin, I am not sure if those suggested approaches from the link you provided are suitable for my current task ☹️. As the proposed approaches looks like a monolithic architecture to me. Reason is I want separate controllers, logics, models in different layers (class library). Please let me know if I misunderstood the article incorrectly. Thank you.

Comment: @SirRufo, or should I use the automapper in the controller level. To convert the DB data into ViewModel?

Or should I implement things like this?
Domain object -> DTOs -> ViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) "true" ViewModels, so those objects which are send to the frontend, always belong to the "interface adapters" layer often also named "presentation layer".

But as you are talking about "Converting the DB data to ViewModel" you probably rather mean "response objects" which belong to the use case layer or even "entities" which belong to the domain model.

Comment: Hi @plainionist, so from use-case layer I need to map entities into response object (DTO) then again convert it into view model?

Comment: @Edward if you want to take Uncle Bob very strict on that then the answer is "yes". Personally i would decide case by case whether a dedicated response object is needed by i definitively recommend having dedicated ViewModel types (see also https://youtu.be/iD4wns3yH44 )